# SQL: Use a predefined list in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, groovy, where-clause

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
        def famlist = selection.getUnique('Family_code')

   ... Where “””...
    and testedWaferPass.family_code in $famlist
    “””...
```

famlist is a list of objects

‘selection’ will change every run, so the list is always changing.

I want to return only columns from my SQL search where the row is found in the list that I have created.

I realize it is supposed to look like: in ('foo','bar')

But no matter what I do, my list will not get like that. So I have to turn my list into a string?

```
('\${famlist.join("', '")}')
```

Ive tried the above, idk. Wasn’t working for me. Just thought I would throw that in there.  Would love some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: you could build list with `FOREACH` loop where inside of the loop you have variable that you add items too. before first time add `(` and each after gets `,` and last item add `)`. What language are you trying to do this?

Comment: Groovy is the language im using to do the main part of the script. It has an SQL query in the middle of it. So if I do a foreach, what would be the each part?

Comment: each part would be an item in `famlist` but I'm not sure how Groovy treats. You would need to ask someone who is familiar with Groovy.

Comment: Add the statement or at least the query itself to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am willing to bet there is a Groovier way to implement this than shown below - but this works.  Here's the important part of my sample script. nameList original contains the string names.  Need to quote each entry in the list, then string the [ and ] from the toString result.  I tried passing as prepared statement but for that you need to dynamically create the string for the ? for each element in the list.   This quick-hack doesn't use a prepared statement.

```
def nameList = ['Reports', 'Customer', 'Associates']
def nameListString = nameList.collect{"'${it}'"}.toString().substring(1)
nameListString = nameListString.substring(0, nameListString.length()-1)

String stmt = "select * from action_group_i18n where name in ( $nameListString)"
db.eachRow( stmt ) { row ->
    println  "$row.action_group_id, $row.language, $row.name"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow that actually works really well. Only problem is that I need to have a parenthesis at the beginning and end of each String

WHERE testedWaferPass.vendor_lot_id in '13274SC2001.000', '13264SC2008.000' 

needs to be
 WHERE testedWaferPass.vendor_lot_id in ('13274SC2001.000', '13264SC2008.000' )

Comment: nameListString  = '(' + nameListString  + ')'

eh?

Comment: omg this worked.....i cant thank you enough. Ive been stalled on this query all day.

Comment: `String nameListString = nameList.collect { "'$it'" }.join( ',' )` then `String stmt = "select * from action_group_i18n where name in ( ${Sql.expand( nameListString )} )"`

Comment: But be careful as this could leave you open to SQL injection

Comment: Exactly, I think I had someone call me out on one of my blog posts in the past where I showed something similar and expand was the correct solution!

Comment: @mikemil Lol, [that was me](http://programmingitch.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/be-careful-using-gstrings-for-sql.html) :-D

Comment: Too funny! I didn't go back and look.  :-)